# jQuery click not firing when clicking image - hide/show table row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Trying to accomplish a pretty easy task. Click an image, and show a hidden table row. Here is the jquery:

```
$(".trigger_44870").click(function() {
   alert('hi');
  $("#target_44870").show();
});
```

Relevant HTML:

```
    <tr>
      <td colspan='13'><img src='https://feedback.primecaremedical.com:8887/purchasing/_assets/images/plus.png' width='1%' class='trigger_44870'></td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="display: none;" id='target_44870'>
      <td colspan=13>Supporting Data</td>
      <td colspan=13>Supporting Data</td>
    </tr>
```

Whenever I click on the image, nothing gets fired from the jquery function.

Any ideas?

https://jsfiddle.net/o4aqbctn/4/

Comment: Your missing jquery reference. Works fine otherwise. https://jsfiddle.net/DinoMyte/o4aqbctn/5/

Comment: It's odd, because in my original script, it's referenced: http://pastebin.com/80rFyijk

Comment: Full page source code: http://pastebin.com/zAKqHvMX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When $(".trigger_44870").click(...) is called, the image element with class="trigger_44870" isn't in DOM yet so the trigger fails.

Move your script code to the bottom of the page (before the `</body>`) or place it inside of an ondomready type event:

```
    $( document ).ready(function() {
      $(".trigger_44870").click( function(){
      alert('hi');
        $("#target_44870").show();
      } );
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

The script is placed in the head of the document and the codeis not included inside $( document ).ready().
A page can't be manipulated safely until the document is "ready." as explained [here](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)

Answer (score 0):

Write the click event inside a document.ready function. Put the whole of document.ready function in a new script tag and place it after your  tag. It will work !!